# Is passing parameters with dictionary OK?

Tags: python

**Context**

There is class 'A' which needs a lot of parameters. And there
are classes B,C,D which depends D->C->B->A way. I have to set
parameters for A while initializing D which would be passed on to C
then to B, A. Now the problem is that the list of parameters is so big
that it would be pain to pass each of it as argument in constructor. So
instead I created a dictionary to pass it on by.

**Question**

In this case, is passing parameters with dictionary OK? If not, are there other way to solve this?

Comment: yes it is not a issue, that is why **kwargs is used in python to represent dictionary data

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is pretty much the use case for `**kwargs`.

Answer (score 0):

just inherit all the classes with class A and then pass a parameter in the dictionary...